# Is it possible to use the mouse wheel for company mode?

Tags: key-bindings, company-mode, scrolling, mouse

I'm using the Cocoa version of Emacs. When company mode presents a list of completions you can use the mouse to select one. It would seem natural to be able to use the mouse wheel to scroll through the selections as well, but it just scrolls the page.

Is it possible to configure the mouse wheel to scroll through company mode completions when the completions are visible?

Comment: Nope. But feel free to file a feature request.